# Heroku db:push not copying database correctly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku

I'm trying to use `heroku db:push` to upload my local postgresql database to the 5Mb shared database Heroku offers. Everything works fine but the database doesn't mirror what I have on my local DB. Some of the records get duplicated and others are just missing. So if I had three records on my local db:

```
cat, dog, banana
```

when I use db:push I end up with:

```
dog, dog, cat
```

My DB has about 100,000 records 3-4 MB total. Any idea how I can fix this?

My database.yml:

development:

```
adapter: postgresql
encoding: unicode
database: myDB
username: myUname
password: myPw
host: localhost
port: 5432
reconnect: true
```

production:

```
adapter: postgresql
encoding: unicode
database: myDBname
username: myUname
password: myPW
host: ec2-23-21-140-215.compute-1.amazonaws.com
```

All this db info I took from

```
heroku config
```

Which gives a database URL with host, username, etc.

Comment: Without revealing anything sensitive, can you show what's in your database.yml config file?

Comment: You might have to specify the local database you want to push onto your production environment (i.e. heroku db:push sqlite://local.db)

Comment: Which Ruby are you running? I had an issue with `db:push` on Ruby 1.9.3 but going back to 1.9.2 solved it.

Comment: Yeah i'm on 1.9.3 and i was thinking that might have something to do with it i will try going down to 1.9.2

Comment: Same thing with ruby version 1.9.2p290.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While convenient, using taps (what db:push uses) may not replicate your data exactly and may run into errors for larger transfers. To import or export data from your production system, we highly recommend using pgbackups instead.

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/import-data-heroku-postgres#from_postgres

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/pgbackups#importing_from_a_backup

Comment: Great this worked, Thanks! I just installed the pgbackup addon for heroku, greated a .dump of my database in pgadmin and uploaded the file to amazon S3. Then i just used pgbackups:restore and the amazon s3 URL and the db copied over fine. Both these links outline what you have to do pretty well. You might have to mess with the amazon s3 permissions.

Answer (score 0):

Push is essentially a copy of the data replacing the tables that are already there (it won't touch tables which are not part of the push).

I'm not sure why you're getting the problems you're having, but you could reset your DB and push to get a clean copy of what you want:

```
heroku pg:reset
heroku db:push
```

Comment: Tried this, didn't work. Whats odd is the bad copy is always different. One time it's missing the first 20 records, try again and those are there and the middle 100 are gone.